# Android project with library builds fine with Eclipse but not with "ant release"

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, apk

I have a project which uses another library project.
When i export a signed apk using eclipse and install it it runs fine.

But, when i build it for release using "ant release", it builds successfully but crashes after installation.

One thing i noticed that the size of apk created via eclipse is larger than the size of apk created via ant. I'm doubting it is not including the library project or some parts of it.

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

My first day with ANT so i dont know much ... any help is appreciated.

=============================================================

## Solved myself:

It was happening because an external jar referenced in the library project was not available in the finally released apk. Manually copying it to the libs folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happening because an external jar referenced in the library project was not available in the finally released apk. Manually copying it to the libs folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

ant task will create apk even if there are no classes to compile (e.g. classpath is wrong)

Comment: there are classes. apps without libraries are working fine using ant release. I'm having problems only with those having library projects. :( So i think the problem is not with classpath.

Comment: I think you were right. The classes.dex file size is lesser when created via ant. how do i fix it ??

Comment: glad you found it. I was having same issue with building using gradle.